# Python - Hexadecimal address code to 2 bytes - 00031322 to 0x01DA

Tags: python, hex, byte

I have been provided by an address code on a siren as 00031322.
And the siren vendor mentioned that this is hexadecimal.

As per specification, they requested to send 2 Bytes Address code and told me that
00031322 (hexadecimal) === 0x01DA in two-bytes hexadecimal.

I am not able to understand , how. When doing the conversion into hex two bytes in python, i get different results
Can someone assist please?

Comment: `0x01DA` is two bytes hexadecimal value. first byte is `01`, second `DA`. I don't understand how you get `0x01DA` from `00031322`. For example `hex(31322)` gives `0x7a5a`. Even with mask for two bytes `hex(31322 & 0xffff)` it gives `0x7a5a`. OR maybe it is not decimal value `00031322` but octal `0o31322` but `hex(0o031322)` gives `0x32d2`

Comment: even if you treat it as two numers `0003` `1322` then `hex(3), hex(1322)` gives `('0x3', '0x52a')`

Comment: True. The vendor mentioned that it is also Hex value. I am not able to figure out. How the conversion of hex 00031322 == 01DA in 2 bytes.

Comment: do you have url to vendor information about hex value ?

Comment: Here is what the document says about the address code in the document. This is the address code in hexadecimal 00031322.   Our siren wireless code transmission way is like the single chip microcomputer simulation PT2262 hardware code mode, Its narrow pulse is 200us,The wide pulse is 600us,The synchronization code is 6.2ms.
Once triggered, 30 strings of this code are sent. Each byte is sent from the highest bit.
Wireless transmission format synchronous code + address code(2 bytes) + data code(1 bytes)
Synchronous code: is 2262 synchronous code,200us high level, 6.2ms low level